Bluetooth connection buggy - have to disconnect and reconnect to get the audio output device on Intel AX201 wireless adapter
So I just installed Kubuntu 24.04 about a month ago on my Acer Aspire A315-58 laptop, I really love it for personal and work usage and how fast and lightweight it is, and have found myself rarely using Windows 11 now.
But Bluetooth is a bit buggy. I have a pair of JLab Go Air POP wireless earbuds, and it tries to autoconnect to the last device it was connected to whenever I bring it out of its case. In most scenarios (on smartphones and any other laptop), this works flawlessly. But on my laptop I have to disconnect and reconnect before I can actually get the audio playback device on my system.
This is what it should normally look like when it's successfully connected: Bluetooth panel, Volume panel.
This is what actually happens when I take it out of the case: Bluetooth panel, Volume panel.
Connecting the first time doesn't work. I have to reconnect it to get it working. And yes, I made sure that I am on pipewire, not pulseaudio, and have updated some libraries for pipewire. I have noticed this problem on Windows 11 too, except autoconnecting on startup works, so it might be a problem with my laptop's Intel AX201 wireless adapter.
I'm kinda stumped, don't know how I can fix this other than the fact that it might be a manufacturing defect. Let me know if I need to provide any other information, and I will edit the post or add some comments if I can. Thanks.

If it is happening on multiple OS it is not a problem with Kubuntu. Therefore I doubt there is anything that needs to or can be fixed.
